# Send an Image from c# server to Android client. Decoding issue

Tags: java, c#, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to send an image Bitmap from a c# server to an App in Android Java and I'm having a problem by decoding the file in java.

Te code in c# to decode an image into a string is as follows:

```
String bildString = ImageToString("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Penguins.jpg");

public static string ImageToString(string path){
    if (path == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    System.Drawing.Image im = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    im.Save(ms, im.RawFormat);
    byte[] array = ms.ToArray();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
}
```

The string is transferred; and here comes the error in Java when I want to recover my image:

```
Bitmap bildAM = StringToBitMap(bildString);

public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
    try{
        byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
}
```

I receive following Exception:

[StackTrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaebR.png)

Comment: post the full stacktrace, `RuntimeException` does not give us any information about the error

Comment: Here is when the Problem exactly comes: `byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);`

Comment: what you linked is not a stack trace of the error, you need to look in your logcat. The problem probably is you are running out of memory when loading the image